# How to get the difference between two timestamps in seconds

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Is there a way I can make a query in MySQL that will give me the difference between two timestamps in seconds, or would I need to do that in PHP? And if so, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You could use the [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) and the [`TIME_TO_SEC()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) functions as follows:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2010-08-20 12:01:00', '2010-08-20 12:00:00')) diff;
+------+
| diff |
+------+
|   60 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You could also use the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function as [@Amber suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528219/mysql-how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-seconds/3528227#3528227) in an other answer:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-08-20 12:01:00') - 
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-08-20 12:00:00') diff;
+------+
| diff |
+------+
|   60 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you are using the `TIMESTAMP` data type, I guess that the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` solution would be slightly faster, since `TIMESTAMP` values are already stored as an integer representing the number of seconds since the epoch ([Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html)). Quoting the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

> When `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is used on a `TIMESTAMP` column, the function returns the internal timestamp value directly, with no implicit “string-to-Unix-timestamp” conversion.
>
> Keep in mind that `TIMEDIFF()` [return data type of `TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff). [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html) values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59' (roughly 34.96 days)

Comment: You can also use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), which does it in a single function - just set the `unit` parameter to `SECOND`.

Answer (score 78):

How about "TIMESTAMPDIFF":

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2009-05-18','2009-07-29') from `post_statistics`
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: If your date column is in another form other that YYYY-MM-DD try doing this: `str_to_date(date_column, '%m/%d/%Y')` within the TIMESTAMPDIFF function for the column that needs it formatting corrected.

Comment: this is a better answer for me since `TIME_TO_SEC` maxes out at `3020399` whereas this returns the correct value.

Comment: Mind you that MySQL subtracts the second date from the first, not the inverse. Ugh.

Comment: I don't like this approach because it does not round. I prefer: 

TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        SECOND,
        start_date,
        end_date
    ) / 3600.0

Comment: @AntonioAndrés Ummm... that doesn't round either.  "timestampdiff(second, '2009-05-18 07:28:17','2009-07-29 14:23:45') / 3600.0" results in 1734.9244 for example.

Answer (score 24):

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts1) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts2)
```

If you want an unsigned difference, add an `ABS()` around the expression.

Alternatively, you can use `TIMEDIFF(ts1, ts2)` and then convert the time result to seconds with `TIME_TO_SEC()`.

Answer (score 18):

Note that the `TIMEDIFF()` solution only works when the `datetimes` are **less than 35 days** apart!
`TIMEDIFF()` returns a `TIME` datatype, and the **max value for TIME is 838:59:59 hours (=34,96 days)**