# MySQL: Get the difference between timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL: how to get the difference between two timestamps in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528219/mysql-how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-seconds)

How can I get the difference in seconds (or any other unit) between two timestamps? If I use `select NOW() - '2012-01-01 00:00:00'` I get `20110121168303` which is wrong.

### My favorite solution

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Answer (score 2):

UNIX_TIMESTAMP returns an offset number of seconds from epoch. Taking the difference between the two of these is in the unit Seconds.

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you : http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,124334,124334