# Timestamp comparison

Tags: php, mysql, time

I am trying to make a clocking system so that people I make websites for can see what I have done when. I have two time stamps in a SQL database.

I want to find out how many hours are between them as I am paid by the hour.
When I query my table, i get the time stamps and assing them to variables

```
$clock_in;
$clock_out;
```

And i want to find the hours/mins between them.
Thanks

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Comment: What are those timestamps? UNIX timestamps? Which are **seconds since 1970**? Which you can **subtract** from each other, then **divide** by the number of seconds per minute and minutes per hour... \*cough\*cough\*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PHP [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function on your SQL timestamp, then simply subtract $clock_in from $clock_out to give you the number of seconds between the two. Divide by 60 to get minutes.

```
$minutes = ($clock_out - $clock_in) / 60
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select time_to_sec(timediff('2010-09-01 03:00:00', '2010-09-01 00:10:00' )) / 3600;

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| time_to_sec(timediff('2010-09-01 03:00:00', '2010-09-01 00:10:00' )) / 3600 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                      2.8333 | 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528219/mysql-how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-seconds) for difference in seconds.