# MySQL datediff strange results

Tags: mysql, datediff

I am getting weird results for the datediff function.
It's zero for different and same timestamps?

```
select datediff('2015-04-25 20:37:45','2015-04-25 05:20:00');
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| datediff('2015-04-25 20:37:45','2015-04-25 05:20:00') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                     0 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+

select datediff('2015-04-25 20:37:45','2015-04-25 20:37:45');
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| datediff('2015-04-25 20:37:45','2015-04-25 20:37:45') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                     0 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: DATEDIFF() returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation

Comment: thanks, what would be the alternative then? I need the time difference in minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the MySQL Manual:

> **[`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)**
>   DATEDIFF() returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation

So what you are getting is correct.

If you are looking for time difference, I would suggest looking into [`TIMEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) or [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).

If you would like to get the difference in minutes, the best way would be `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.

Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2015-04-25 20:37:45','2015-04-25 05:20:00');
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2015-04-25 20:37:45','2015-04-25 05:20:00') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                               -917 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

`datediff` will do the calculation on the dates and find the difference in days,
however you can use [timestampdiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) for different difference like `hour`,`min` etc as

```
mysql> select timestampdiff(hour,'2015-04-25 05:20:00','2015-04-25 20:37:45') as hour;
+------+
| hour |
+------+
|   15 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use TIMEDIFF() function instead of DATEDIFF if you want to compare two timestamps with difference lower than day. For example:

```
select TIMEDIFF('2015-04-25 20:37:45','2015-04-25 05:20:00');
```

or for result in sec:

```
select TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2015-04-25 20:37:45','2015-04-25 05:20:00'));
```

For more details:

[MySQL: how to get the difference between two timestamps in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528219/mysql-how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-seconds)

hope this helps :)