# Select all records in the last 2 minutes - MySql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my mysql table

```
-----   -----------   -------------------
b_id    update_time   update_time_text
-----   -----------   -------------------
A:340   1436507350    10-07-2015 11:19:10
A:340   1436507707    10-07-2015 11:25:07
A:340   1436509704    10-07-2015 11:58:24
A:340   1436507828    10-07-2015 11:27:08
```

And this is my query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE b_id='A:340' AND update_time < (NOW() - 120) // 120 is 2 minutes
```

How do i select records in the last 2 mintues since my query is returning empty records and i'm not sure if i have to take unix time(update_time) or the readable time(update_time_text)

Comment: Dates/times adhere to a specific format in SQL. This ain't it. Fix that and then get back to us.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `date_sub` and `interval 2 minute`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE b_id='A:340' AND update_time < date_sub(NOW() - interval 2 minute) // 120 is 2 minutes
```

Answer (score 2):

as update_time is a unix timestamp field then replace your `NOW()` with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE b_id='A:340' AND update_time >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 120)
```

records older than 2 minutes:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE b_id='A:340' AND update_time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 120)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE b_id='A:340' AND TIME_TO_SEC(update,NOW())<=120
```

If you want difference of time in second more detail refer this link

[MySQL: how to get the difference between two timestamps in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528219/mysql-how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE b_id='A:340' AND update_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me but in my case the update_time was a timestamp.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE b_id='A:340' AND update_time > date_sub(NOW(), interval 2 minute);
```