# Time difference in seconds between given two dates

Tags: bash, shell, date

I have two dates as follows:

```
2019-01-06 00:02:10 | END
2019-01-05 23:52:00 | START
```

How could I calculate and print the difference between START and END dates in seconds?

For above case I would like to get something like:

```
610
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: will make sure about it next time.

Comment: You could also fix this one, it's not too late! Click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54103307/edit) link under the question to get started. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming **GNU** implementation based OS, you can use `date`'s option `%s` and `-d` to calculate the time difference in `seconds` using command substitution and arithmetic operations.

```
START="2019-01-05 23:52:00"
END="2019-01-06 00:02:10"

Time_diff_in_secs=$(($(date -d "$END" +%s) - $(date -d "$START" +%s)))
echo $Time_diff_in_secs
```

Output:

```
610
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: That's not part of bash, and it's not portable. Do you know what operating system the OP is running?

Comment: I didn't vote down. It makes sense to wait until the questioner has shown what he has already tried.

Comment: @ghoti: Sir, I can see the `bash` tag in the question, so was able to answer accordingly. Also, i didn't expected a Downvote for the answer.

Comment: Bash runs on more than Linux, and the `date` command is not part of bash. Bash is the default shell on macOS. If I attempt your solution on macOS, I get an error, because `date -d` *means something else* in different operating systems. If your answer is OS-specific and the question is not, you should note in your answer that it is only applicable in certain environments. Ideally, your answer should be *portable* so that it will work in any environment. That makes it valuable to whoever finds the question in the future, regardless of what OS they run.

Comment: I do understand that I did not add my way of fixing it -- but certainly I was clueless because I had other things to figure -- how to get to these date's itself as I am using mysql and getting a response into a text and then finding the difference between START and END record. @User123 - Thank you. I will make sure to add my fix from next time.

Comment: Ah, so this was an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). You could do this with much better performance right in MySQL. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528228/1072112) answer.

Answer (score 2):

With bash and GNU date:

```
while read d t x x; do
  [[ $x == "END" ]] && end="$d $t" 
  [[ $x == "START" ]] && start="$d $t"
done < file

end=$(date -u -d "$end" '+%s')
start=$(date -u -d "$start" '+%s')

diff=$(($end-$start))
echo "$diff"
```

Output:

```
610
```

---

See: `man date`

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is difficult verging on impossible using pure bash. Bash doesn't have any date functions of its own. For date processing, most recommendations you'll get will be to use your operating system's `date` command, but the usage of this command varies by operating system.

In BSD (including macOS):

```
start="2019-01-05 23:52:00"; end="2019-01-06 00:02:10"
printf '%d\n' $(( $(date -j -f '%F %T' "$end" '+%s') - $(date -j -f '%F %T' "$start" '+%s') ))
```

In Linux, or anything using GNU date (possibly also Cygwin):

```
printf '%d\n' $(( $(date -d "$end" '+%s') - $(date -d "$start" '+%s') ))
```

And just for the fun of it, if you can't (or would prefer not to) use `date` for some reason, you might be able to get away with gawk:

```
gawk 'END{ print mktime(gensub(/[^0-9]/," ","g",end)) - mktime(gensub(/[^0-9]/," ","g",start)) }' start="$start" end="$end" /dev/null
```

The `mktime()` option parses a date string in almost exactly the format you're providing, making the math easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
START="2019-01-05 23:52:00"
END="2019-01-06 00:02:10"
parse () {
    local data=(`grep -oP '\d+' <<< "$1"`)
    local y=$((${data[0]}*12*30*24*60*60))
    local m=$((${data[1]}*30*24*60*60))
    local d=$((${data[2]}*24*60*60))
    local h=$((${data[3]}*60*60))
    local mm=$((${data[4]}*60))
    echo $((y+m+d+h+mm+${data[5]}))
}
START=$(parse "$START")
END=$(parse "$END")
echo $((END-START)) // OUTPUT: 610
```

Answer (score 1):

Was trying to solve the same problem on a non-GNU OS, i.e. macOS. I couldn't apply any of the solutions above, although it inspired me to come up with the following solution. I am using some in-line Ruby from within my shell script, which should work out of the box on macOS.

```
START="2019-01-05 23:52:00"
END="2019-01-06 00:02:10"

SECONDS=$(ruby << RUBY
require 'date'
puts ((DateTime.parse('${END}') - DateTime.parse('${START}')) * 60 * 60 * 24).to_i
RUBY)

echo ${SECONDS}
# 610
```