# Number of seconds a user has had account enabled during a specific time period

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the number of seconds a user has had his/her account enabled during a specific 7 day time period.

We store `enabled_start` and `enabled_end` along with the `user_id` in our database.

How many seconds did the user have his/her account enabled between 2022-04-22 00:00:00 - 2022-04-27 23:59:59?

What makes it complicated:

- There is no `enabled_end` set for `id` 5, meaning account is currently enabled.
- Account was enabled once our time period started (`id` 2).

How does one deal with these open intervals?

I gave up, hopefully someone knows better!

| id | user_id | enabled_start | enabled_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 123 | 2022-04-26 12:13:38 | NULL (=account is still enabled) |
| 4 | 123 | 2022-04-25 15:22:36 | 2022-04-25 17:32:11 |
| 3 | 123 | 2022-04-24 11:16:46 | 2022-04-25 05:10:08 |
| 2 | 123 | 2022-04-15 14:44:00 | 2022-04-23 10:58:53 |
| 1 | 123 | 2022-03-29 16:44:15 | 2022-04-04 11:22:39 |
| 0 | 123 | 2022-03-24 13:44:15 | 2022-03-25 09:11:39 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: how to get the difference between two timestamps in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528219/mysql-how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-seconds) Unclear that id 5 should return, perhaps have a `case when` for those edge cases.

Comment: Use the MYSQL internal function [TimestampDiff][https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-calculations.html].

Comment: The referenced answers does not answer how to deal with open ended intervals, which is part of this question

Comment: You can use COALESCE to map null to a specific time. Something like: `select user_id
 , sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, enabled_start, coalesce(enabled_end, '2022-04-27 23:59:59'))) 
from t where enabled_start >= ... and enabled_end <= '2022-04-27 23:59:59'
group by user_id`

Comment: What do one do when a dude marks your question as duplicate when it is not?